# Upgrading from 2.7.1 to 2.7.2

Tags: ee2-upgrades

I'm have trouble upgrading versions. I was going from 2.5.5 to 2.7.2. It's added a table called exp_upgrade_log but now it's getting hung up between 2.7.1 and 2.7.2. This is what it says:

```
Preparing to update from 2.7.1 to 2.7.2. Awaiting acceptance of license terms.
Updating to 2.7.2
```

I've just got a blank page on the update wizard. There's nothing happening in this log table either. Any tips on fixing this upgrade process?

this is the url the wizard has left.

```
/admin.php?C=wizard&M=do_update&language=english&ajax_progress=yes
```

Comment: Can you try enabling "Error Reporting" in your admin.php and tell us which error(s) are popping up?

Comment: It's getting hung up with Structure. Probably need to upgrade it too.

Comment: Upgrade Structure first. They have released some updates recently that help fix 2.7.X compatibility. You should be good to go after that!

Answer (score 1):

As odd as this sounds, try the upgrade in another browser. It's possible something about that browser version is getting stuck on the ajax part of the upgrade.